# solving euler-lagrange equation in constrained functional optimization

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, euler-lagrange-equation

The problem to solve is the minimization of a functional of two functions, $F(y,z) = \int_a^b f(y,z)dx$ , subject to a constraint $g(y,z,y',z') = 0$. The augmented functional is then $L(y,z,y',z') = \int_a^b [f + \lambda g]dx$. $\lambda$, *y* and *z* are functions of *x*.

The Euler Lagrange equations lead to the coupled differential equations:

$ g(y,y') = 0 $

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} - \lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial z'} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial z'} \lambda '=0$

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \lambda \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} - \lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y'} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial y'} \lambda '=0$

I have, as usual in functional minimization problems, two boundary conditions for *y* and *z*. So I guess I have two options:

1 - solving the three equations in the three unknown functions *y*, *z* and $\lambda$. But in this case how do I get boundary conditions for $\lambda$ from the ones I have?

2- From the last two equations I can get rid of $\lambda$, by solving for $\lambda$ and $\lambda$' and equating the derivative of $\lambda$ to $\lambda$'. This results in a second order differential equation for *y* and *z* to be solved simoultaneously with the constraint. The problem here is that this differential equation is very complex, it involves quotients of polynomials in *y*, *z*, *y*' and *z*' which seems to be quite untractable...

So what would be the best method to solve this problem?